# How can I just get one record instead of duplicates using ActiveRecord in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, has-many-through

I have a model as follows:

```
Campaign
  has_many :companies, :through => :contacts
```

There are many contacts with the same company.  I just want one instance of each company.

I tried the following:

```
@campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
@companies = @campaign.companies
```

But this shows me all the companies for every contact I believe.  At least that's what the output looks like.

How can I make sure that only a single instance of a company is added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `:through`, it's usually useful to use the `:uniq` option, so you don't get repeated results

```
has_many :companies, :through => :contacts, :uniq => true
```

Answer (score 1):

The currently-accepted solution by "j." *will* work, however it is very inefficient because it removed the duplicates in Ruby, instead of in SQL. It actually just runs `.uniq!` on the returned results.

The efficient and, in my opinion, proper way to do this is:

```
has_many :companies, :through => :contacts, :select => "DISTINCT companies.*"
```

It might not be as pretty, but it will get you what you want, will use no extra memory, and will be much faster.